# Property id is not defined in type Node in PhpStorm/WebStorm

Tags: javascript, dom, phpstorm, webstorm

Php/WebStorm is reporting this wierd warning in my JavaScript code stating that property `id` is not defined in the element/node. Thing is, the element is a `firstChild` element fetched from the parent element.

```
function hideChildAndUpdateID(title) {
    let parent = document.getElementById('parent');
    let child = parent.firstChild;

    // Hiding the child.
    child.style.display = 'none';
    // Temporary ID so we can find it later.
    child.id = 'child-tmp-id'; // Warning occurs here
}
```

And this is the entire message from Php/WebStorm

```
Property id is not defined in type Node less... (Ctrl+F1) 
Inspection info: This inspection reports assignments to undefined properties of explicitly type-annotated variables.
```

This code itself actually works. The `child` element gets it's `id` changed to whatever I set it to, but this warning is anoying me.

I have tried using `child.setAttribute('id', 'child-tmp-id')`, but that did not work properly.

Is there a convention when dealing with `firstChild` or it's just a Php/WebStorm thingy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nodes can be more than just elements and don't necessarily have an `id` property. Try using `firstElementChild` instead that returns the first child that is an element:

```
function hideChildAndUpdateID(title) {
    let parent = document.getElementById('parent');
    let child = parent.firstElementChild;

    // Hiding the child.
    child.style.display = 'none';
    // Temporary ID so we can find it later.
    child.id = 'child-tmp-id'; 
}
```

Comment: I have in the mean time used the `setAttributeNode` along with `createAttribute` and that worked too, but this is way nicer. Thanks.